# Como usar o "break" no blade template?

Tags: php, laravel, template, laravel-blade

Estou desenvolvendo um modal de checklist onde serão cadastrados os novos dados do protocolo. Cada atributo do item serão informados pelo usuário e estas informações serão cadastradas a tabela `checklist_protocolo` do banco de dados.

Mas as informações como a descrição do item e o modelo do checklist são consultados de outras tabelas do banco de dados. As informações do do modelo (tabela `checklist_modelo`) eu consegui carregar no modal, mas as informações da descrição do item (tabela `checklist_item`) eu não consegui, pois é necessário itera-lo dentro do loop e os dados estão saindo duplicados.

Como solucionar este problema? Segue as imagens que exemplificam o problema.

**Modal Checklists**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Modal Checklists [ERRO] - dados duplicados**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Modelo ER**
<
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue os trechos dos códigos responsáveis por executar esta funcionalidade.

**Método edita da classe ProjetoController.php:**

```
     //Método que  redireciona para a página de editar o  Projeto
     public function edita($id, Request $request)
     {  
        $projetoCriado = Projeto::findOrFail($id);

        $this->flagStatusDoc =   $projetoCriado->status_documentacao == 'A' ? true : false;
        $this->flagAprovacao =   $projetoCriado->situacao_projeto == 'AP' ? true : false;
        $this->flagStatusPagamento  =  $projetoCriado->usu_auto_pag_id != null &&  $projetoCriado->dt_pag_autorizado != null ? true : false;
        $flagHabilitaEmenda  =  $projetoCriado->valor_interno == 0 ? false : true;
        $flagHabilitaTabsFinanceiro  =  $projetoCriado->projeto_atividade_id  == null && $projetoCriado->elemento_despesa_id == null && $projetoCriado->fonte_recurso_id == null
        && $projetoCriado->dt_ordenador == null &&  $projetoCriado->valor_ordenador  == 0 ? false : true;

        $usuarios = User::where('autoriza', '=', 'S')->get(); // armazena todos os usuários que tem permissão de autorização (autoriza = S)
        $usuariosAtivos = User::all(); // armazena todos os usuários cadastrados no sistema
        $setores = Setor::all();
        $proponentes = Proponente::all(); 
        $tipoProjetos = TipoProjeto::all(); 
        $modalidadeApoios = ModalidadeApoio::all();


        $ocorrencias =  DB::table('ocorrencias')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'ocorrencias.usuario_id')
            ->where('ocorrencias.projeto_id','=',  $id )
            ->select('ocorrencias.id', 'ocorrencias.origem', 'ocorrencias.tipo', 'users.name', 'ocorrencias.descricao', 'ocorrencias.dt_ocorrencia' )
            ->get();


        $categoriaInstrumentos = CategoriaInstrumento::all();
        $modalidadeLicitacoes = ModalidadeLicitacao::all();

        $historicoErratas = HistoricoErrata::where('projeto_id', '=',  $id)->get();
        $historicoNotificacoes = HistoricoNotificacao::where('projeto_id', '=',  $id)->get();

        $projetoAtividades = ProjetoAtividade::all();
        $elementoDespesas = ElementoDespesa::all();
        $fonteRecursos = FonteRecurso::all();

        $detalhamentoEmpenhos = DetalhamentoEmpenho::where('projeto_id', '=',  $id)->get();
        $detalhamentoLiquidacoes = DetalhamentoLiquidacao::where('projeto_id', '=',  $id)->get();
        $detalhamentoPagamentos = DetalhamentoPagamento::where('projeto_id', '=',  $id)->get();
        $detalhamentoEmendas = DetalhamentoEmenda::where('projeto_id', '=',  $id)->get();

        $localidades = Localidade::all(); 
        $localidadesAtivas = Localidade::where('ativo', '=', 'S')->orderBy('localidade', 'asc')->get(); 


        $permissoesAprovacao = verificarPermissao('Aprovação');
        $permissoesJuridico = verificarPermissao('Juridico');
        $permissoesGestaoContrato = verificarPermissao('Gestão Contratos e Convênios');
        $permissoesFinanceiro = verificarPermissao('Financeiro');
        $permissoesOcorrencia = verificarPermissao('Ocorrência'); 
        $permissoesAbas= verificarPermissao('Abas do Projeto'); 
        $permissoesDadosGeraisProj= verificarPermissao('Dados Gerais do Projeto'); 



        //Variáveis da funcionalidade "Movimentar Projeto"
       $movimentacaoResponsavel = MovimentacaoResponsavel::where('projeto_id', '=',$id)->orderBy('dt_movimentacao','desc')->first();
       $usuarioDestino = empty($movimentacaoResponsavel) ? Auth::user() :  User::where('id','=', $movimentacaoResponsavel->usu_destino_id)->first(); 
       $usuarioResponsavel =   $usuarioDestino;

       $checklistsModelo = ChecklistModelo::all();
       $checklistsEstrutura = ChecklistEstrutura::all();

       $checklistsEstruturaModelo =  ChecklistModelo::whereIn('id', $checklistsEstrutura->pluck('modelo_id'))->get();


        $statusDocumentacao =  $projetoCriado->status_documentacao == 'P' ? 'Pendente' : 'Autorizado';
        $statusProjeto =  $projetoCriado->situacao_projeto;

        switch ($statusProjeto){
            case 'AA':
                $statusProjeto = 'Aguardando Autorização';

            break;
            case 'AP':
                $statusProjeto = 'Aprovado';
            break;
            case 'CS':
                $statusProjeto = 'Cancelado Suspenso';
            break;
            case 'RP':
                $statusProjeto = 'Reprovado';
            break;
            default:
                $statusProjeto = 'Aguardando Autorização';
            break;
            }

        $userAutorizaDoc = User::find($projetoCriado->usu_autoriza_doc_id); 
        $usuarioAutorizaDoc =  $userAutorizaDoc == null ?  'Indefinido' : $userAutorizaDoc->name ;

        $userAutorizaProjeto = User::find($projetoCriado->usu_situacao_id); 
        $usuarioAutorizaProjeto =   $userAutorizaProjeto == null ?  'Indefinido' : $userAutorizaProjeto->name ;

        $userAutorizaPagamento = User::find($projetoCriado->usu_auto_pag_id); 
        $usuarioAutorizaPagamento =   $userAutorizaPagamento == null ?  'Indefinido' : $userAutorizaPagamento->name ;

        $countLocalidadesProjeto = count(LocalidadeProjeto::where('projeto_id','=',$id)->distinct()->get());
        $localidadesProjeto = Localidade::join('localidades_projeto', function ($join) use ($id) {
                            $join->on('localidade.id','=','localidades_projeto.localidade_id')
                            ->where('localidades_projeto.projeto_id','=',  $id ); })->distinct()->get();  


        //Variáveis da aba de Aprovação
        $valorEmenda = DB::table('emendas_detalhes')
                    ->where('projeto_id', $id)
                    ->sum('valor');



       $valorAprovado = $valorEmenda + $projetoCriado->valor_aprovado_total;
       $checklistsItens = ChecklistItem::all();

       //Variáveis da aba de Financeiro
       $valorEmpenho = DB::table('detalhamento_empenho')
                    ->where('projeto_id', $id)
                    ->sum('valor_empenho');

       $valorLiquidacao = DB::table('detalhamento_liquidacao')
                    ->where('projeto_id', $id)
                    ->sum('valor_liquidacao');

       $valorPagamento = DB::table('detalhamento_pagamento')
                    ->where('projeto_id', $id)
                    ->sum('valor_pagamento');


       //Contador do Checklist de Protocolo
       $countChecklistProtocolo = count(ChecklistProtocolo::where('projeto_id','=', $id)->distinct()->get());  


       $checklistProtocolo =  ChecklistProtocolo::where('projeto_id','=', $id)->distinct()->get();

       $arrayChecklistProtocolo = [];
       $arrayChecklistProtocolo =  (array) array_values($checklistProtocolo->toArray());


       //Modelo do Protocolo
      $modelo = ChecklistModelo::where( 'id','=',$arrayChecklistProtocolo[0]['modelo_id'])->distinct()->get();
      $modeloProtocolo = (array) array_values($modelo->toArray());



      //Consulta de todos os 'id' de itens do modelo selecionado
      $itens_id = DB::table('checklist_estrutura')
      ->where('checklist_estrutura.modelo_id','=', $modeloProtocolo[0]['id'])
      ->select('checklist_estrutura.itens_id' )
      ->get();



      //Converte o conjunto de dados para Array
      $array_itens_id = (array) array_values($itens_id->toArray());

      $arrayIdItens = [];
      foreach ($array_itens_id  as $item) {
          $arrayIdItens[] = $item->itens_id;
      }

      //Consulta  de todos as descrições do itens (descricao_item) do modelo selecionado
      $array_descricao_item =  DB::table('checklist_itens')->whereIn('id',$arrayIdItens)->get();



      $arrayItens = [];
      $arrayItens =  (array) array_values($array_descricao_item->toArray());

    //dd($arrayItens);

   // dd($checklistProtocolo);

  /*   
     foreach ($checklistProtocolo as $chktProtocolo) {
              $protocolo =  new stdClass;
              $protocolo->projeto_id =  $arrayChecklistProtocolo ;
              $protocolo->modelo_id =  $modeloProtocolo[0]['id'];
              $protocolo->modelo_nome =  $modeloProtocolo[0]['modelo'] ;
              $protocolo->item =  $chktProtocolo->item;
              $protocolo->item_descricao_id = $chktProtocolo->item_descricao_id ;
              $protocolo->item_nome = "bffff";
              $protocolo->sim_nao = $chktProtocolo->sim_nao;
              $protocolo->nao_atende = $chktProtocolo->nao_atende ;
              $protocolo->dt_validade = $chktProtocolo->dt_validade ;
              $protocolo->pagina_documento = $chktProtocolo->pagina_documento ;
              $protocolo->observacao = $chktProtocolo->observacao ; 
    } */

    //  foreach ($array_descricao_item  as $itens) {  
  // dd($protocolo->projeto_id);




        return view('admin.projeto.edita', ['projeto' => Projeto::find($id), 'permissoesAprovacao' =>  $permissoesAprovacao, 'permissoesJuridico' => $permissoesJuridico,
                'permissoesGestaoContrato' =>  $permissoesGestaoContrato , 'permissoesFinanceiro' => $permissoesFinanceiro,
                'permissoesOcorrencia'=> $permissoesOcorrencia, 'permissoesDadosGeraisProj' => $permissoesDadosGeraisProj,
                'permissoesAbas' =>  $permissoesAbas, 'setores' => $setores, 'proponentes' => $proponentes, 'tipoProjetos' => $tipoProjetos, 'usuarios' => $usuarios, 'usuariosAtivos' => $usuariosAtivos,
                'localidades' => $localidades,'modalidadeApoios' => $modalidadeApoios, 'usuarioResponsavel'=>$usuarioResponsavel,'statusDocumentacao'=>$statusDocumentacao,
                'usuarioAutorizaDoc' => $usuarioAutorizaDoc,'localidadesAtivas'=> $localidadesAtivas,'flagHabilitaEmenda'=> $flagHabilitaEmenda, 'flagHabilitaTabsFinanceiro' => $flagHabilitaTabsFinanceiro,
                'flagStatusDoc' =>$this->flagStatusDoc, 'flagAprovacao' =>  $this->flagAprovacao, 'flagStatusPagamento' => $this->flagStatusPagamento,
                'countLocalidadesProjeto' =>  $countLocalidadesProjeto, 'localidadesProjeto' => $localidadesProjeto, 'statusProjeto' => $statusProjeto, 'usuarioAutorizaProjeto' =>  $usuarioAutorizaProjeto,
                'usuarioAutorizaPagamento' => $usuarioAutorizaPagamento, 'categoriaInstrumentos' => $categoriaInstrumentos, 'modalidadeLicitacoes' => $modalidadeLicitacoes,
                'historicoErratas' => $historicoErratas, 'historicoNotificacoes' =>    $historicoNotificacoes, 'checklistsEstruturaModelo' =>  $checklistsEstruturaModelo,
                'projetoAtividades' => $projetoAtividades, 'elementoDespesas' => $elementoDespesas, 'fonteRecursos' =>  $fonteRecursos,
                'detalhamentoEmpenhos' => $detalhamentoEmpenhos, 'detalhamentoLiquidacoes' => $detalhamentoLiquidacoes, 'detalhamentoPagamentos' => $detalhamentoPagamentos,
                'detalhamentoEmendas' =>  $detalhamentoEmendas , 'valorEmenda' => $valorEmenda, 'valorAprovado' =>  $valorAprovado, 'valorEmpenho' => $valorEmpenho,
                'valorLiquidacao' => $valorLiquidacao, 'valorPagamento' => $valorPagamento, 'ocorrencias' => $ocorrencias, 'countChecklistProtocolo' => $countChecklistProtocolo,
                'checklistsModelos' => $checklistsModelo, 'checklistsEstruturas' => $checklistsEstrutura, 'checklistsItens' =>  $checklistsItens,
                'checklistsProtocolos' => $checklistProtocolo,'arrayItens' => $arrayItens, 'modeloProtocolo' => $modeloProtocolo]);
     }
```

**Página edita.blade.php:** Eu tentei colocar a variável `break` na condicional para sair o nome da descrição do item mas ocorreu um erro.

```
 <!--Inicio do modal de Checklist do Projeto--> 
  <div class="modal fade modal-default" id="modalChecklist" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="examplePositionCenter"
                 role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog2 modal-center">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Checklists</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                             <input type="hidden" id="idProjeto" name="idProjeto" value="{{$projeto->id}}">
                             <input type="hidden" id="idModeloProcesso" name="idModeloProcesso" value="{{$modeloProtocolo[0]['id']}}">
                             <label class="control-label">Modelo</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="modeloProcesso" value="{{$modeloProtocolo[0]['modelo']}}" disabled>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-18">
                             <input type="hidden" id="idProjeto" name="idProjeto" value="{{$projeto->id}}">
                             <table id="checklist" class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive toggle-arrow-tiny" >
                                <caption></caption>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Item</th> 
                                            <th>Descrição</th>
                                            <th>Sim/Não</th>
                                            <th>Não Atende</th>
                                            <th>Data de Validade</th>
                                            <th>Página do Documento</th>
                                            <th>Observações           </th>
                                            <th class="text-center"></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="bodyUsers">

                                @foreach($checklistsProtocolos as $checklistProtocolo)
                                 @foreach($arrayItens as $item) 
                                   <tr>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_protocolo" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->item}}"  size ="2"></td>
                                       <td>{{$item->id == $checklistProtocolo->item_descricao_id ? $item->descricao_item :  break }}</td>   


                                       <td><input type="checkbox" name="simNao_protocolo"{{$checklistProtocolo->sim_nao == null ? '' : 'checked'}}></td>
                                       <td><input type="checkbox" name="naoAtende_protocolo" {{$checklistProtocolo->nao_atende == null ? '' : 'checked'}} ></td>
                                       <td><input type="date" class="form-control" name="dtValidade_protocolo" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->dt_validade}}"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="paginaDoc_protocolo" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->pagina_documento}}" size ="1"></td>
                                       <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="paginaDoc_protocolo" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->observacao}}" size ="1"></td>

                                   </tr>
                                    @endforeach 
                                 @endforeach
                               </tbody>
                        </table>



                        </div>

                        </div><!--Fim do modal-body-->

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <center>
                            <a id="btnSalvarChecklist" type="button" class="btn btn-primary salvarChecklist" data-dismiss="modal"  align="center" style="width: 300px; height: 40px">Salvar</a>
                        </center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  <!--Fim do modal do Checklist do Projeto-->
```

**Classe AppServiceProvider.php**

O comando `break` não é suportado na versão Laravel que estou usando, logo dentro do método `boot()` da classe  `AppServieProvider` eu definir a seguinte função.

> public function boot()
>       {
>           Blade::directive('break', function() { return ""; });
>       }

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use Blade;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
  /*   public function boot()
    {
        //
    } */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('break', function() { return "<?php break; ?>"; });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

ERRO: , mas ocorreu o erro apresentado nesta imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual versão do laravel você está usando? aparentemente parece a 5.6, estou certo?

Comment: Olá @AlvaroAlves, a versão do Framework Laravel é 5.5.28

Answer (score 0):

Coloquei como resposta pois não ia caber no comentário:
pelo que eu entendi, caso nao tenha o id ele tem que dar o break, você faz assim:

```
@foreach($arrayItens as $item) 
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_protocolo" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->item}}"  size ="2"></td>
      <td>{{$item->id == $checklistProtocolo->item_descricao_id ? $item->descricao_item :  break }}</td>   
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="simNao_protocolo"{{$checklistProtocolo->sim_nao == null ? '' : 'checked'}}></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="naoAtende_protocolo" {{$checklistProtocolo->nao_atende == null ? '' : 'checked'}} ></td>
      <td><input type="date" class="form-control" name="dtValidade_protocolo" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->dt_validade}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="paginaDoc_protocolo" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->pagina_documento}}" size ="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="paginaDoc_protocolo" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->observacao}}" size ="1"></td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Caso seja feita assim não resolveria seu problema?

```
@foreach($arrayItens as $item)
    @if($item->id != $checklistProtocolo->item_descricao_id)
        <?php break 1; ?>
    @endif
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_protocolo" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->item}}"  size ="2"></td>
      <td>{{$item->descricao_item}}</td>   
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="simNao_protocolo"{{$checklistProtocolo->sim_nao == null ? '' : 'checked'}}></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="naoAtende_protocolo" {{$checklistProtocolo->nao_atende == null ? '' : 'checked'}} ></td>
      <td><input type="date" class="form-control" name="dtValidade_protocolo" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->dt_validade}}"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="paginaDoc_protocolo" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->pagina_documento}}" size ="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="paginaDoc_protocolo" value="{{$checklistProtocolo->observacao}}" size ="1"></td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Oi, @Alvaro Alves, eu fiz o teste como você recomendou. Mas não funcionou pois apenas o primeiro registro foi impresso e os demais não foram exibidos. Acredito que a função break saiu dos dois loops ao invés de sair apenas do primeiro loop.

Comment: Vou fazer uma alteração, pode ser que funcione, só um momento :D

Comment: tente utilizando o break 1, como está na [documentação do php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.break.php) é capaz de funcionar para o que você quer

Comment: Eu utilizei o break conforme  sugerido, mas os dados ficaram duplicados como na segunda imagem desta pergunta.

Comment: Olá, @Alvaro Alves. Obrigada pelo retorno. Eu testei o <?php break 1; ?>, mas apareceu somente 1 registro.